# OpenGLES links error in xcode6: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: opengl-es, xcode6, arm64

After update to `Xcode 6.0.1`, my project build error at link phase. I don't know why, but I'm sure that's something about `OpenGLES`. Because when I delete the code about that, it build fine.

Following is the full error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAGLContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glDisable", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView setupGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glGenVertexArraysOES", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView setupGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glGenBuffers", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView setupGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glBufferData", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView setupGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glVertexAttribPointer", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView bindShaderAttributes] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glDeleteVertexArraysOES", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView tearDownGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glMapBufferOES", referenced from:
      _addVertex in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glDrawArrays", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView drawRect:] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glBindBuffer", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView tap:] in PPSSignatureView.o
      -[PPSSignatureView pan:] in PPSSignatureView.o
      -[PPSSignatureView setupGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glClearColor", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView drawRect:] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glDeleteBuffers", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView tearDownGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glClear", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView drawRect:] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glUnmapBufferOES", referenced from:
      _addVertex in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glBindVertexArrayOES", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView drawRect:] in PPSSignatureView.o
      -[PPSSignatureView setupGL] in PPSSignatureView.o
  "_glEnableVertexAttribArray", referenced from:
      -[PPSSignatureView bindShaderAttributes] in PPSSignatureView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and the import code: import `OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are not linking to OpenGLES.

In your project settings, go to 'build phases' and in 'Link Binary with Libraries' add OpenGLES.framework.